# Force / Encourage user to view Sharepoint site with Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Okay, very limited experience with Sharepoint, so please be gentle...!

We are running Sharepoint 2007 on our intranet for a smallish number of users. From what I can tell, when it comes to managing documents, checking stuff in and out etc, Sharepoint just works a lot better in Internet Explorer because of the ActiveX plugin.

Therefore, as a way to *train* our users to open the site with IE, is it possible to popup a message when the user visits the site with a non-IE browser, to ask them to use IE. Maybe I can insert a snippet of JavaScript into the page or maybe there is some option or technique available to make this happen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could also create shortcuts for users on desktop like `iexplore.exe "http://mysharepointserver"` so SharePoint opens in IE even if some other browser is the default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, if you find a javascript that does exactly that, you can easily include it in SharePoint by pasting the code in a Content Editor WebPart (with the  tag) which you can add to your page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for this question. I was thinking of doing this asswell and forgot :)
Now I got the anwser for you and me both...

Javascript will do it for you. Either in content editor webpart (on single page) or by modifying master page (this will inform you in all the sites that uses this master page).

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp) have basic data how to get browser information, but i think that 
[this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml) webpage has more info about it.

I decided to make a script for myself, and tested it:

```js
 if (!/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    alert("This is not IE!");
 }
```

I just added this to our company MOSS 2007 site: (our site use a jQuery)

```js
<span id="alert" style="position:absolute; top:0; left: 250px; width: 300px; background-color: #ee2211; color: white; text-align: center; valign: middle; height: 50px; font-size: 13pt;">Attention: This is not (recomended) IE browser! <b>(x)</b></span> 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../Miscellaneous/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../Miscellaneous/jquery.SPServices-0.5.8.min.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript">
    $("#alert").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($.browser.msie){
            $("#alert").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```